# Query latest record for each ID in DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

We have a table like this:

```
user_id | video_id | timestamp
      1          2           3
      1          3           4
      1          3           5
      2          1           1
```

And we need to query *latest* timestamp for *each* video viewed by a specific user.

Currently it's done like this:

```
response = self.history_table.query(
            KeyConditionExpression=Key('user_id').eq(int(user_id)),
            IndexName='WatchHistoryByTimestamp',
            ScanIndexForward=False,
        )
```

It queries all timestamps for all videos of specified user, but it does way huge load to database, because there can be thousands of timestamps of thousands videos.

I tried to find solution on Internet, but as I can see, all SQL solutions uses GROUP BY, but DynamoDB has no such features

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways I know of doing this:

**Method 1 GSI Global Secondary Index**

GroupBy is sort of like partition in DynamoDB, (but not really). Your partition is currently `user_id` I assume, but you want `video_id` as the partition key, and `timestamp` as the sort key. You can do that creating a new GSI, and specify your new sort key `timestamp` & partition key `video_id`. This gives you the ability to query for a given video, the latest timestamp, as this query will only use 1 RCU and be super fast just add `--max-items 1 --page-size 1`. But you will need to supply the `video_id`.

**Method 2 Sparse Index**

The problem with **1** is you need to supply an ID, whereas you might just want to have a list of videos with their latest timestamp. There are a couple of ways to do this, one way I like is using a Sparse Index, if you have an attribute, called `latest` & set that to true for the latest `timestamp`, you can create a GSI and choose that attribute key `latest`, but not you will have to manually set and unset this value yourself, which you have to do in lambda streams or your app.

That does seem weird but this is how NoSQL works as opposed to SQL, which I myself am battling with now on a current project, where I am having to use some of these techniques myself, each time I do it just doesn't feel right but hopefully we'll get used to it.

Comment: Oh yeah btw keep in mind you must make an LSI on creation of you table which can be a bit annoying if you are doing it after the fact.

Comment: how about maintaining a _table-latest_ where we'll save only the latest record and keep updating whenever a newer record arrives. This way creating an index may not be required? Both the main table and _latest_ tables will have key & sort-keys in addition to other fields.. 
Direct all date-range queries to main table; and query the _-latest_ table for getting the newest record.

Comment: Yes that is another legitimate way, it just all depends on your use case, if you what to be able to sort all values, you'll need an index, if you want to maintain a small subset, doing what you suggest in Lambda streams may be better.